# What's the limit on push notifications a device can receive per day per app?

Tags: android, ios, notifications

I see answers that there is no limit to APNS, but that's for the total number of push notifications a server can send, not per user. So if a server wants to send 1 notification to 1 billion users, that's ok.

What if I need to send n notifications to 1 user, in day? How many will he receive?

I know that if my server sends too many push notifications to a single device, Apple will rate limit those and the user will receive fewer notifications than what I have sent.

Do we have a rough idea of this number? Im interested in the results of both Android and iOS. Thanks

Comment: How many will he receive - how many you send all are recive

Comment: I don't think there is any limit.

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple Technical Note TN2265](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)

> There are no caps or batch size limits for using APNs. The iOS 6.1
>   press release stated that APNs has sent over 4 trillion push
>   notifications since it was established. It was announced at WWDC 2012
>   that APNs is sending 7 billion notifications daily.
>
> If you're seeing throughput lower than 9,000 notifications per second,
>   your server might benefit from improved error handling logic.
>
> It can take a while for the dropped connection to make its way from
>   APNs back to your server just because of normal latency. It's possible
>   to send over 500 notifications before a write fails because of the
>   connection being dropped. Around 1,700 notifications writes can fail
>   just because the pipe is full, so just retry in that case once the
>   stream is ready for writing again.

Comment: that says there is no cap on server -> apple, it does not say anything per device. Please read my question again

Comment: server Your Server. if your server able to send n notifications to 1 User then APNS will forward all that notification to 1 USER.

Comment: as first Line There are no caps or batch size limits for using APNs. Means you can send n number of notification to APNS.

Comment: yes you can send, but Apple has a rate limiter. So if I send you 10000 notifications, Apple will forward only n to you. Maybe n=100, I don't know, Im asking for this number

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit. You can refer below link :

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: that says there is no cap on server -> apple, it does not say anything per device. Please read my question again

Answer (score 0):

In Android, there's no limitations to how much notifications are send. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) you can find the paid services and [here](https://firebase.google.com/features/notifications/) you will see that

> Usage is free and unlimited.

You can use **Firebase** for both **Android** and **iOS**.